# IEnumerable<IMyInterface> Implicitly From Class[] But Not From Struct[]. Why?

Tags: c#

Given:

```
public interface IMyInterface{

}

public class MyClass:IMyInterface{
     public MyClass(){}
}

public struct MyStruct:IMyInterface{
     private int _myField;

     public MyStruct(int myField){_myField = myField;}
}
```

Why can I write:

```
IEnumerable<IMyInterface> myClassImps = new[] {
    new MyClass(),
    new MyClass(),
    new MyClass()
};
```

But not:

```
IEnumerable<IMyInterface> myStructImps = new[]{
    new MyStruct(0),
    new MyStruct(1),
    new MyStruct(2)
};
```

Which gives me the following warning:

**Error 29  Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyApp.MyNS.MyStruct[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyApp.MyNS.IMyInterface>'**

And must instead be written:

```
IEnumerable<IMyInterface> myStructImps = new IMyInterface[]{
    new MyStruct(0),
    new MyStruct(1),
    new MyStruct(2)
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is array covariance. [This specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572%28VS.71%29.aspx) talk about it:

> For any two reference-types A and B, if an implicit reference conversion (Section 6.1.4) or explicit reference conversion (Section 6.2.3) exists from A to B, then the same reference conversion also exists from the array type A[R] to the array type B[R], where R is any given rank-specifier (but the same for both array types)

A simpler example of this that also fails is

```
int[] c = new int[0];
object[] d = c;
```

while

```
string[] c = new string[0];
object[] d = c;
```

works fine. You are basically trying to do the same thing. You have an array of value types `MyStruct` and you are trying to implicitly cast it to `IMyInterface`, which is not covered by the array covariance specification.

Comment: The question is tagged with C# 3.0 so what variance are you talking about?

Comment: Understand that I do see there are gaps in my answer, but the one thing I don't understand about this explanation is that if this is really just a covariance issue, then why can he instantiate assign the enumerable with an array of 'MyClass's, but not with an array of 'MyStruct's.  This in particular was why I thought this has something to do with boxing.

Comment: @L. Moser Right, it is because it is a difference between value types and reference types. I don't know why the CLR team chose to have this restriction. Your boxing explanation may be right. They didn't want to worry about copying the array onto the heap.

Answer (score 1):

The one that works does implicit boxing, then casting to an IMyInterface.  The problem is that the compiler doesn't necessarily know that the struct is a IMyInterface.  Boxing then casting gets you that describe your object as an IMyInterface.

I'm actually reading about this in CLR Via C# right now, so if you think I've misrepresented this, please correct me.

Comment: “[T]he compiler doesn't necessarily know that the struct is a `IMyInterface`” But he has the definition of the struct, so he does know that it does implement the interface.

Answer (score 0):

A struct is not a class.  There are different rules when instantiating them.  Without researching it, my guess is that the type can not be inferred in your first example because it is not a class.  When it is explicit, there is no problem.