# Invalid implicit cast when casting array of interfaces to an array of structs

Tags: c#, interface, struct, compiler-errors, implicit-conversion

I have a `struct` that implements some `interface`. This works fine until I have an array of the `struct` implementation and try to implicitly cast that array to another array of the `interface` type. (See the below code example)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MainNS
{
    public interface IStructInterface
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }

    public struct StructImplementation : IStructInterface
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get { return "Test"; }
        }
    }

    public class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            StructImplementation[] structCollection = new StructImplementation[1]
            {
                new StructImplementation()
            };

            // Perform an implicit cast
            IEnumerable<IStructInterface> castCollection = structCollection;    // Invalid implicit cast
        }
    }
}
```

When compiling the above code, I get the error:

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'MainNS.StructImplementation[]' to 'MainNS.IStructInterface[]'

If I change `StructImplementation` to a `class` I have no problems, so I'm assuming what I'm trying to do is either not valid; or I'm being blind and missing something obvious.

Any advice or explanation for this would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

In case anyone else has this issue and using a different approach is less than ideal (as was the case in my situation), I worked around my issue using the [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) method [`Cast<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx). So in the example above, I would perform the cast using something like:

```
IEnumerable<IStructInterface> castCollection = structCollection.Cast<IStructInterface>();
```

There is a good article on MSDN about [Variance in Generic Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228359%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which I found very useful.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825276/ienumerableimyinterface-implicitly-from-class-but-not-from-struct-why

Comment: You answered your own question.  The error explains this error, what you are trying to do is not valid C# code, the solution is to use a class.

Comment: @Ramhound I assumed I had done something that was invalid in C# - I was looking more for an explanation or some direction to such an explanation, as I have now found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array variance ony allows for the **reference preserving** case, and so only works for classes. It is essentially treating the original data as a reference to a different type. This is simply not possible with structs.

Answer (score 2):

Convariance, which you are using here, is not supported for structs, because they are value types and not reference types. See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2009/10/04/understanding-csharp-covariance-and-contravariance-8-struct-and-void.aspx) for a little bit more info.